# Ionic picture to Laravel back-end

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, upload, camera

I would like to send a picture from Ionic app to Laravel back-end, but I keep getting `FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR (Code=1)` in the app.

Taking picture works:

```
$scope.openCamera = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: 1,      // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album
                encodingType: 0     // 0=JPG 1=PNG
            });
            function onSuccess(FILE_URI) {
                $scope.picData = FILE_URI;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
            function onFail(message) {
                alert('Error (' + message + ')');
            }
        }
    }
```

But sending keeps throwing error:

```
$scope.send = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var myImg = $scope.picData;
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "post";
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            options.fileName = 'someFileName.jpg';
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            var params = {};
            params.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            options.params = params;
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(myImg, encodeURI(SERVER + 'user/post'), win, fail, options);
        }
    }
```

I have noticed that when I look at the `error.source` that I can't find physically the file listed. I can't debug on browser (lack of camera) so I am deploying everything to my phone.

```
var fail = function (error) {
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                alert("upload error source " + error.source);
                //alert("upload error target " + error.target);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i had this problem and i found a solution, a bit late, but will helps, someone:

```
var headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+ $localStorage.get('token')};
            options.headers = headers;
```